# How to determine the hyperlink with a JSON response for a website (assume the website supports JSON)?

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am working on a small VBA program to extract data from multiple websites.  I got some results but with lot of issues.  For this particular question, assume I want to extract the "status" from this link `https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_housings/0334724802`. Currently, I use the code below:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate "https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_housings/0334724802"
While IE.Busy = True: DoEvents: Wend

On Error GoTo checkstatus
debug.Print IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("status active vam")(0).innertext


' Clean up
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

It works most of the time but I still need to add additional waiting time as `IE.Busy` is not very reliable (tried the `READYSTATE`). I also have to catch the the class name as `status active vam` can be changed to something else like `status planned vam`

Thanks to a member of this site, I know about JSON, I know how to run the API, and parse the JSON result but I have not figured out how to convert a standard hyperlink to the one that can gives back JSON.

Comment: The documentation for how to return a JSON should be in the documentation for the api you are using.

Comment: And for your existing code add While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend , and then add a timed loop testing for presence of desired node and/or change in class attribute value.